# Could not find SDK Bing.Maps.Xaml, Version=1.113.0601.1

Tags: windows-8.1, bing-maps

I am working with windows 8.1 store app.In my app using the bing map sdk. I have added the bing map sdk extention.But I got the error "Could not find SDK Bing.Maps.Xaml, Version=1.113.0601.1".Please give a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The version of Bing Maps you are referencing is for Windows 8 only. There is a new version that is for Windows 8.1. The new version has some additional features and a lot of bug fixes. You can find the Windows 8.1 Bing Maps control here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/224eb93a-ebc4-46ba-9be7-90ee777ad9e1

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have installed the latest version of the sdk since the one you've added the reference to is not for Window 8.1.

Also, one other possible solution consists in editing and removing the reference to the Bing Maps elements directly in your csproj file.

So to do as said, here are the steps:

- Edit the csproj (or vbproj) file directly as xml content (right-click, unload the project and right-click Edit the csproj)
- Remove the element that references the Bing Maps control inside the  section
- Save the document and reload the project then add the reference using the usual way

If, for an unknown reason it won't work, it might be useful to uninstall and reinstall the Bing Maps extension (SDK) and do the same process as before by removing and adding back the reference to the extension.